Why are ants biting the skin of a cat?
There's a long-haired cat in my neighborhood that likes to come to my house to eat with my cats. Lately I noticed that there's a bald spot on the cat's lower back, and it turns out there are ants in that spot biting the cat's skin. Why don't the cat try to get rid of the ants? And what caused the ants to go there in the first place?
I washed the cat with some water to get rid of the ants, but I'm worried that this will happen again if the cat don't already try to get rid of the ants by itself.

The cat may simply have been lying near an anthill. I would be surprised if the ants are at all related to hair loss, though.

I would also have reached for a fine comb for this purpose, rather than water. More effective, and less confusing for the cat. Though some cats have no problem with being washed if it is done properly, and indeed some have been known to voluntarily swim.

If I were you I would do at least one of the following:

Stop the socialization of the foreign cat and my cats.
Take the foreign cat to a vet, to decide if the bald spot is infectious and transmissible or not.

Optionally, if time and money are not an important issue, I might also try to treat the foreign cat of the infection.
Additionally, I would closely monitor my cats for signs of unusual hair loss.
Of course, if that cat is not stray, I would definitely contact its owners.
